# Can't seem to pass a model to an ActionAsPdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wkhtmltopdf, tempdata, rotativa

I need to generate a pdf copy of each partner's AR and for that I'm trying to pass a model to another view via TempData but it always returns null.

Here's my code below.

```
public ActionResult GenerateARPDFs(string dateasof)
{
    dateasof = "03-31-17";
    var report = new ReportViewModel();
    report.AccountsReceivable = _bhelper.GetAccountsReceivable("", "", "", DateTime.Parse(dateasof)).
                                Where(w => !w.SOANum.Any(y => char.IsLetter(y)) ||
                                w.SOANum.Contains("SOA")).ToList<AccountsReceivable>();

    foreach (var partner in report.AccountsReceivable.Select(m => m.BP).Distinct())
    {
        TempData["MyModel"] = report;
        var actionResult = new ActionAsPdf("AccountsReceivableReport_PerPartner", new { employeecode = partner })
        {   
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.Letter,
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(5, 5, 5, 5),
            MinimumFontSize = 12
        };
        var byteArray = actionResult.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
        var fullPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArPDF"].ToString() + @"\" + partner + ".pdf";
        var fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        fileStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Generation successful!";
    return View();
}



public ActionResult AccountsReceivableReport_PerPartner(string employeecode)
{
    var report = (ReportViewModel)TempData["MyModel"];
    report.AccountsReceivable = filter by partner here////....;
    return View(report);
}
```

But when it reaches the AccountsReceivableReport, the tempdata is always null. 
I can just recall the SP on the AccountsReceivableReport() but that would take longer.

Is there an issue with passing a tempdata to an ActionAsPdf?
I'm using rotativa btw.

When I inserted a breakpoint, the TempData["MyModel"] is successfully filled with the results but when i reach the method for `AccountsReceivableReport_PerPartner()` it is now null.

If i try to change it from ActionAsPdf to ViewAsPdf it returns an error on the buildPdf part

Answer (score 0):

> TempData in ASP.NET MVC is basically a dictionary object derived from
>   TempDataDictionary. TempData stays for a subsequent HTTP Request as
>   opposed to other options (ViewBag and ViewData) those stay only for
>   current request. [detail](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/06/using-tempdata-asp-net-mvc.html)

Try session for this:

```
public ActionResult AccountsReceivableReport_PerPartner(string employeecode)
{
    var report = Session["MyModel"] as ReportViewModel;
    return View(report);
}
```

Comment: even when I switched it to a session, it still is null

Comment: Session["MyModel"] = report; set this too?

Comment: Yep I also changed that part.

Comment: On the part after I set that, Session["MyModel"] did have a value But when it reached the other method, it now is null.

Comment: Set this outside each loop

Comment: That was the original position of the code. Still is null. I tried to put it inside the loop in case it is being destroyed earlier for some reason.